# Why does loading an integer in MIPS require a 'Load Word' function rather than a 'Load Address'?

Tags: assembly, mips, cpu-architecture

In the following code, in order to print an integer one must use 'lw' rather than 'la' like when you try to load a string. Why is this any different from loading a string since a string and integer are both stored at addresses in RAM? If I was unclear on anything please comment below.

```
.data
myInt: .word 200  #This is a word or integer
.text
# prints an integer to the screen
li $v0, 1
lw $a0, myInt
syscall
```

Comment: Because an integer can also be stored in a register. Why pass the address of an integer in register when you can pass the integer in the register directly.

Comment: @RossRidge Thank you for the reply, but a character and a string can essentially be translated to a binary integer. This is what sparked my question. So why can't these be loaded as words?

Comment: A character can be stored in a register but a string can't be. Not if strings can be longer than 4 characters.

Comment: @RossRidge That makes a lot of sense; so a character can be stored using load word or not really due to character-string consistency?

Comment: A character is an integer, usually an 8-bit integer. So you'd use LB to load it from memory normally.  Note to load constant integers into a register you can use the LI instruction. eg: `li $a0, 200`.